# Query with dynamic table name

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I would like to change a dynamic SQL statement in a parametrized statement, but in the query the table name is dynamic. So I tried to paramrtrize the whole statement in this way, as I saw in the newCRMsupport's answer in [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a84ac0aa-3870-4852-851e-0722fd476042/pass-a-tablename-as-a-parameter-in-adonet?forum=adodotnetdataproviders):

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

string sqlStr = " DECLARE @sqlSubstr nvarchar(max) SET @sqlSubstr = N'UPDATE quotename(@tempTable) = SET @flag = 1 WHERE @tempCol = @tempColVal' EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlSubstr";
command.CommandText = sqlStr;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tempTable", TemporaryTableName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flag", flagToUpdate);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tempCol", ImportRegister.TemporaryTableKeyColumn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tempColVal", sourceRow[ImportRegister.TemporaryTableKeyColumn]);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But when I run it, I have an Exception. "Must declare calar variable @tempTable", and I can't figure out what I am missing.
Thanks

Comment: This is a sign of a poor design. If you need to use dynamic SQL like this you've designed the database wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dynamic SQL like this is a sign of a poor design, either on the database design or on the application design.

However, assuming the design can't be changed, the problem with your current SQL statement is that you are not actually using dynamic SQL.
A dynamic SQL for this would look like this:

```sql
DECLARE @sqlSubstr nvarchar(max) = N'UPDATE '+ quotename(@tempTable) +N' 
    SET '+ quotename(@flag) +N' = 1 
    WHERE '+ quotename(@tempCol) +' = @tempColVal;

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlSubstr, N'@tempColVal varchar(2)', @tempColVal;
```

Note the parameters for the table name and column names are concatenated into the string representing the SQL you are executing.
Also, please note I've added `quotename` to the column names as well.

However, I'm not sure that this provides a full-proof protection against SQL injection attacks.  The use of `quotename` does provide some protection but I'm pretty sure that it is possible to overcome this.
To truly protect yourself you must white-list all the identifiers - so you first need to query `information_schema.columns` to make sure everything is safe.

Only once you do that, you can be sure the code is SQL Injection safe.
While we're at it, [you really should stop using AddWithValue already.](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Here's a revised version of your code:

```cs
string sqlStr = @"DECLARE @sqlSubstr nvarchar(max) = 
    N'UPDATE '+ quotename(@tempTable) +
    N' SET '+ quotename(@flag) +
    N' = 1 WHERE '+ quotename(@tempCol) +' = @tempColVal' 
    IF EXISTS(
        -- make sure both columns exists in the table
        SELECT 1
        FROM Information_schema.Columns
        WHERE Table_Name = @tempTable
        AND Column_Name IN(@flag, @tempCol)
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Column_Name) = 2 
    )
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlSubstr N'@tempColVal nvarchar' @tempColVal"; -- I had to guess the data type

command.CommandText = sqlStr;
command.Parameters.Add("@tempTable", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TemporaryTableName;
command.Parameters.Add("@flag", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = flagToUpdate;
command.Parameters.Add("@tempCol", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ImportRegister.TemporaryTableKeyColumn;
command.Parameters.Add("@tempColVal", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = sourceRow[ImportRegister.TemporaryTableKeyColumn]);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Looks like at a cost of couple requests to Information_schema client can build a regular `UPDATE` command with the only parameter `@tempColVal`

Comment: @Serg I argue that the dynamic approach here is wrong to begin with - as I wrote at the beginning of my answer. IMHO, ideally CRUD statements should not be dynamic unless there's a good reason for it - and good reasons for it are hard to find.

Comment: I tried but I had an error "the parameterized query expects the parameter '@tempColVal' which was not supplied"

Comment: Sorry, I somehow forgot to add it to the `sp_executeSql`. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works. The reason for this is that I want to be safe to SQL injections, so I thought to transform the dynamic queries in parametrized queries, because I don't have control on the database, so I can't create parametrized stored procedures on the DB.

Comment: You don't need stored procedures to write SQL Injection safe code. You need parameterized queries. My point is not against parameters, it's against dynamic SQL - to be accurate - against dynamic SQL for the purpose of writing a single, generalized SQL for different tables.